# How to find child pipeline run id of execute pipeline

Tags: azure, apache-spark

I want to find the expression to find the run id of child pipeline of Execute pipeline, currently I am using:

```
@activity('Execute Pipeline1').Output.pipeline.RunId
```

which is giving error. How can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the expression "@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output" gives a JSON which is converted to a String and
 hence anything beyond the output value is not being parsed as a JSON.

One way to get past this is by using a custom activity chained to the execute pipeline activity and parse it using .NET code.

Hope this helps.